# ¿Cómo resolver "SecurityError. Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object" al ejecutar pruebas automatizadas en Cypress?

Tags: javascript

Al ejecutar pruebas automatizadas en Cypress me está dando el siguiente error:

> SecurityError. Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object.

Buscando en internet encontré que el motivo del error es que el nombre del dominio de la ventana principal y la ventana secundaria son diferentes, incluso en el mismo sitio. El problema es causado por el mecanismo d seguridad del navegador, básicamente es que he intentado acceder a algún objeto al cual no tengo permiso, probablemente un iFrame cargado de otro dominio. También encontré que la solución está en cambiar la información de dominio de las dos páginas para que sea la misma.
Finalmente, alguien me comentó que le había sucedido lo mismo y que existe alguna variable al instalar cypress, en la configuración que hay que poner en true o en false (no recuerda bien).
¿Alguien podría ayudarme en esto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes probar usando la opción `"chromeWebSecurity": false` en tu archivo de configuración de Cypress.

Más allá de ésto, es posible analizar las sugerencias en la [documentación de Cypress](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/web-security#Insecure-Content). Esencialmente, ese escenario cargando un frame de otro dominio tiene como lío que uno nunca controla el contenido del frame. Valdríá la pena pensar si no hay que validar el contenido del frame en pruebas separadas (uno no le envía alegremente cookies o datos de la ventana padre a los frame hijos :) )

Comment: Hola, corazón, me sigue dando el mismo error, yo utilizo firefox, tiene algo que ver?? Saluditos

Comment: @Nane las respuestas no se aceptan si no resuelven el problema. Las preguntas deben tener tooooooooooooda la info. La documentación dice claramente que esto sólo funciona para Chrome...

Comment: Mil disculpas, de veras, es q soy nueva en este mundo de la automatización, pues entonces, lo mío no tiene solución para firefox?

Comment: Edité la respuesta con lo poco que sé o he visto. Espero que sirva (o que alguien más pueda aportar otra cosa)

Comment: Agradezco su ayuda.